Typesetting Zig Programming Language: Seeking Listing or Minted Environment
As I delve into the Zig programming language, I'm exploring options for effectively typesetting code snippets in my documents. While LaTeX offers powerful tools like the "listing" and "minted" environments for various languages, I'm unsure if similar options exist for Zig.
I'm seeking guidance on whether a specific environment or package within LaTeX is tailored for typesetting Zig programming language. Any insights or recommendations on effectively displaying Zig code snippets in LaTeX documents would be greatly appreciated.

I've never come across 'Zig', I suspect I'm not alone: could you link to details?

So I found https://ziglang.org/: sounds like starting from C highlighting then modifying in listings would work?

Pygmentize (the tool used by minted for syntax highlighting) seems to have a lexer for zig. Can you add a test document to your question which includes an example for zig code?

Minted seems to work ok:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{zig}
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    std.debug.print("Hello, World!\n", .{});
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}


